# How to create count only the value from each column Excel

Tags: excel, pivot

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTSQ7.png]

I try to create a pivot chart which can display something like the result below which only shows the counts for closed month within the open month, and leave other not closed month into the month where it closed.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/87ryA.png]

Thanks so much.

Comment: I updated the result example since I uploaded wrong one.

Comment: The data looks like it will produce the Pivot Chart you show. What's the issue you have?